# Extracting 5 characters from string

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java and struggling with a possibly simple thing.

I have strings in different formats. An example string is given below

```
New_System-Updater-For-19974774.ftw
```

Basically i want to extract the number "**19974774**". For this i want to find the index where "." is, as there will be only dot in the string and then go back and extract the 8 characters.

Is there a simple way of doing it?

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: Well, it sounds like you need to use the `String.indexOf` and `String.substring` methods. Try those, and see whether you can solve it yourself. (I'd also suggest fixing up your title, assuming the 5 was meant to be an 8... Is it always 8 characters?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String s = "New_System-Updater-For-19974774.ftw";
int positionOfDot = s.indexOf('.');
String withoutDotFtw = s.substring(0,positionOfDot);
String number = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("-")+1,positionOfDot);
```

You can try something like this

Comment: this will pick everything after the dot. I don't think thats what he wants.

Comment: You need to make `s.lastIndexOf("-") + 1` otherwise it will take the `-` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want 8 char before dot i suggest :

```
String tst = "New_System-Updater-For-19974774.ftw";
int indexOfDot = tst.indexOf(".");
String extract = tst.substring(indexOfDot-8, indexOfDot);
System.out.println(extract);
```

If size of digit it not 8 digit, use regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tst);
if(matcher.find()){
    extract = matcher.group(1);
}
System.out.println(extract);
```

Comment: What if the number is more than 8 chars.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer what if it's not?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static string GetNumberFromName(String name) {
    String myString = "New_System-Updater-For-19974774.ftw";

    return myString.split("\\d+\\.")[0].split("\\d+")[0];
}
```

Comment: Note: obviously just replace the test "myString" variable with the "name" variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to retrieve the numbers you want.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D*(\\d*)\\D*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that you want the number in front of the last period in your string. You should use a regex ideally, but this may be simpler if regex is unfamiliar.

```
String string = New_System-Updater-For-19974774.ftw";
String[] splitString = string.split('.');
if(splitString.length > 1) {
  String secondToLastString = splitString[splitString.length - 2]; //second to last string
  int i = secondToLastString.length - 1;
  for(; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(!Character.isDigit(secondToLastString.charAt(i))) {//If not digit break out and use that index as bound
      break;
    }
  }
  return secondToLastString.substring(i + 1);
} else {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("string doesn't have proper format");
}
```

Or just use a regex

```
String string = New_System-Updater-For-19974774.ftw";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d*)\\.[^\\.]*").matcher(string);
if(matcher.find()) {
  return matcher.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is always a `-` before the digits this will work:

```
String initial = "New_System-Updater-For-19974774.ftw";
String firstSplit = initial.substring(initial.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
String finalSplit = firstSplit.substring(0, firstSplit.indexOf("."));
```

Assuming the number of digits are fixed to 8, this will work:

```
String initial = "New_System-Updater-For-19974774.ftw";
String firstSplit = initial.substring(0, initial.lastIndexOf("."));
String finalSplit = firstSplit.substring(firstSplit.length()-8, firstSplit.length());
```

`finalSplit` will be your number.